# What is the difference between a map legend and a map key?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between a map legend and a map key? Please answer soon please.

Comment: [A quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=map+legend+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=map+legend+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512j0i15i22i30l3j0i22i30l4j0i15i22i30.6341j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows that the terms are synonymous (at least in the eyes of certain institutions). Though some (eg [Tutors.com](https://tutors.com/lesson/map-key-definition-symbols-examples))  regard 'key' as a hyponym of 'legend'.

Answer (score 1):

"A **map key** is an inset on a map that explains the *symbols*, provides a *scale*, and usually identifies the type of map *projection* used. Technically, the key is part of the **map legend**. The key explains the symbols, while the legend holds the key and other information."

Later in the text:

"Today we use both phrases to mean the same thing, but the map key is technically found in the map legend."

Source: [https://tutors.com/lesson/map-key-definition-symbols-examples#:~:text=A%20map%20key%20is%20an,the%20key%20and%20other%20information](https://tutors.com/lesson/map-key-definition-symbols-examples#:%7E:text=A%20map%20key%20is%20an,the%20key%20and%20other%20information).